Is contingency just temporality?
Aristotle makes a close connection between contingency and temporality. The contingent is something that comes to exist. However, this connection is seldom made explicit in modern philosophy that I've read. It can sometimes be inferred from the description of what it is to be necessary or contingent, but it's seldom obvious, and I hadn't drawn the explicit connection until recently. I'm looking into it now, and can't find a specific discussion of the connection, so here are some questions I have not been able to answer:

Are there any examples of temporal objects that are not contingent?

Are there any examples of contingent objects that are not temporal?

Are there any examples of atemporal objects that are not necessary?

Are there any examples of necessary objects that are not atemporal?

Failing such examples, is there a principled reason to keep these concepts distinct?

There are things that seem to be on the border of being temporal and atemporal in the sense that there is no time at which they do not exist but they do seem to have a beginning and ending with the universe itself. Examples are laws of nature and matter/energy. Could such things be examples to answer questions 1 to 4?


ADDENDUM:
A couple of people have brought up possible worlds semantics in the comments. My view of possible worlds semantics is that it is a nice technique to give a semantics to the prior notions of modality (and an almost-but-not-quite-right analysis of intensional properties), but it can't be used to answer questions like this because the notion of a possible world is parasitic on the prior notion of possibility. In particular, saying that a temporal object would be necessary if it occurred in all possible worlds is morally equivalent to just stipulating that some temporal objects may be necessary. It doesn't give any insight into how that might make sense. If you give me a set of possible worlds in which object A exists in all the worlds, I can just say you are missing the possible worlds in which A doesn't exist.
However, these mentions of possible worlds reminded me of the examples of truths that are allegedly necessary but not a priori. For example it is alleged that a person is necessarily the child of his particular parents and that water is necessarily H2O. I've never found these arguments all that compelling, but they do provide a possible pathway to the examples I'm looking for.

+1 Simon Critchley characterizes the analytical method, in distinction to Continental preoccupations, as being ahistorical and atemporal. I would take it a step further and say that contingency conceptually effaces but metaphysically necessitates  temporality; I recently came across Possible Objects (SEP) which seems to address contingent aspect of entities. I'd say any object that is impossible, such as a square circle, are a priori not contingent. As for atemporal considerations, that seems a function of views on eternality.

Would semantic contingencies count? I.e. the solutions to a system of differential equations, or the sum of the angles of an Euclidian triangle?

@gs, I don't think I understand your use of "semantic contingency".

I think the triangle is a worse example than the solutions. Generalized, something like a timeless one-way logical implication, if A therefore B. Since the solution set of a system of differential equations is not unique to that system of differential equations, the statement "if (a certain system of differential equations) therefore (a certain set of solutions)" cannot be reduced to logical identity.

I'm proposing that (a certain set of solutions) could be a kind of timeless contingency, since it is a logically non-identical consequence of the proposition (a certain system of differential equations).

This was based on an alternative meaning of "possible" and "necessary" in terms of generation/corruption as later found in scholastics, e.g. in Aquinas's third way:"We find in nature things that are possible to be and not to be, since they are found to be generated, and to corrupt, and consequently, they are possible to be and not to be." After Leibniz, this meaning fell out of use. The modern meaning of "possible" and "necessary" has no relation to temporality or generation/corruption.

Now necessity is interpreted as presence across possible worlds and one can set up their worlds to have non-contingent temporal objects (say, creation and salvation events, necessarily existing prophets and saviors), contingent atemporal objects (say, artistic designs, physical laws in a multiverse), etc.

@David Gudeman To provide a sound basis to answer your questions it would help that you give us some reference to the technical terms "contingent" and "temporal" from Aristotle's work. To know his definitions, the original Greek words and some context.

@JoWehler, I'm not looking for answers in Aristotle's terms, as I noted in the first sentence or two, I have an idea what he would have said about it. I'm more interest in the modern understanding of those concepts.

@DavidGudeman OK, then we skip Aristotle. And I assume you take the possible-worlds-definition of "contingent" and "necessary". How do you define "temporal" and "atemporal" as used in your post?

@Conifold, I've added an addendum to explain why I don't find your answer compelling.

@JoWehler, I've added an addendum to address possible worlds.

@DavidGudeman Apparently you dismiss the possible-worlds semantics. But then your working-definition of "contingent", "necessary", "temporal" and "atemporal" remains open. Without hearing your definition I cannot propose an answer to your questions concerning these terms. I vote to close until you provide more clarity of this point.

@JoWehler, the question is exploring the meanings of the modal words. I can't hope to give a definition before answering the question. As to "temporal", it means an object that changes over time and "atemporal" means an object that does not change over time.

And what about things where the concept of time does not apply at all? E.g., ideas or propositions.

@JoWehler, an object to which time does not apply does not change over time.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I think there's a slight confusion of terms here, modern philosophy does not usually deal with 'necessary' or 'contingent' objects. The terms necessary and contingent are broadly applied to truths, statements about the way things are. So, for example, 'That is a red ball' is contingent because it is possible that ball may not have been red. 'All bachelors are unmarried' is necessary because there is no possibility of a married bachelor (assuming logical impossibilities are, in fact, impossible).
(To be fair, modern philosophy also does not often deal with temporal objects, but it does come up in discussions about time and persistence).
If we did apply the necessary/contingent terminology to objects, I think most modern philosophers would be happy to say that all objects are contingent except the theoretical existence of God, who would be necessary. The same would be true of temporality.
That is, however, definitional.

If x is temporal, it has a beginning.
If x is contingent, it 'comes to exist'.
If something comes to exist, it has a beginning.
Therefore, if x is contingent, it has a beginning.
Therefore, if x is contingent, then x is temporal.

I'm not sure it achieves anything though.

I was using "object" in its broad, philosophical sense to include things like events and states of affairs.
